# Overlapping multiple circular images using Flexbox or Grid

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to create overlapping badges using either grid or flexbox, I'm not able to achieve it correctly.

I want something like this

[image]

[image: Overlapping Images]

```
 <div class="grid">
    <img src="" alt="" class="image">
    <img src="" alt="" class="image">
</div>
```

This is the CSS, it doesn't work

```
.grid
{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.image
{
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    align-self: center;
}

.image:nth-child(odd)
{
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.image:nth-child(even)
{
    grid-column: 2 / -1;
}
```

I know this isn't much to go on but I'm really bad at CSS, some advice is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your proposed layout is not suited to CSS-Grid.

Comment: In general you should stack the images and then adjust the offset using margins

Comment: I understand thanks. Is there any resource, you recommend that I can follow?

Comment: Nope...but I'm sure you can search Google or Stack Overflow for something similar

Comment: Which part of the code makes it circular? The image or not added `border-radius`?

Comment: Images I have are already circular, it's just a layout (overlapping images) issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) property to adjust each element by X or Y position.

If you want to overlap from first, then you can always modify the DOM order or even the [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

```css
.images-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.images-container.vertical {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.circular-image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circular-image:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(-50px);
}

.stack-from-left .circular-image:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: -1;
}

.circular-image:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateX(-100px);
}

.stack-from-left .circular-image:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: -2;
}

.circular-image:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translateX(-150px);
}

.stack-from-left .circular-image:nth-child(4) {
  z-index: -3;
}

.vertical .circular-image:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateY(-50px);
}

.vertical .circular-image:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(-100px);
}

.vertical .circular-image:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translateY(-150px);
}
```

```html
<div class="images-container">
  <div class="circular-image">
    <img src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image" alt="" class="circular-image">
  </div>
  <div class="circular-image">
    <img src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image" alt="" class="circular-image">
  </div>
  <div class="circular-image">
    <img src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image" alt="" class="circular-image">
  </div>
  <div class="circular-image">
    <img src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image" alt="" class="circular-image">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="images-container stack-from-left">
  <div class="circular-image">
    <img src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image" alt="" class="circular-image">
  </div>
  <div class="circular-image">
    <img src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image" alt="" class="circular-image">
  </div>
  <div class="circular-image">
    <img src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image" alt="" class="circular-image">
  </div>
  <div class="circular-image">
    <img src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image" alt="" class="circular-image">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="images-container vertical">
  <div class="circular-image">
    <img src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image" alt="" class="circular-image">
  </div>
  <div class="circular-image">
    <img src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image" alt="" class="circular-image">
  </div>
  <div class="circular-image">
    <img src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image" alt="" class="circular-image">
  </div>
  <div class="circular-image">
    <img src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image" alt="" class="circular-image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this must be too much to ask but I can you show me how the overlapping from first would work. Again I'm really new at CSS

Comment: @ShivamSood I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, 1 last question, if the incoming images are unknown is there a way to make it dynamic?

Comment: @ShivamSood But that is not part of the layout problem. You can open a new question so that there is no mix-up.

Comment: @ShivamSood please don't open a new question for the same issue, to add another requirement. I added a duplicate that cover unknown number of elements

Comment: @TemaniAfif That looked like Shivam was asking for a script which would make the source of images dynamic. Outside of CSS scope. Otherwise, your solution fits fine.